# AngularJS: Inspect request body from $resource factory

Tags: angularjs, post, factory

This is undoubtedly a beginner question - the fact that my google searches arent coming back with much suggests to me that I'm trying to do something I shouldn't even want to do! But I'm struggling to think of what to try next....

Basically I have an object that I want to post to a REST API, which cut down looks something like this:

```
build = {
    "hostname": "server1",
    "id": "589077a935a68f3b16162460",
    "osedition": "577503af1dde347724d1b83e" 
}
```

….and depending on the osedition value, the URL it needs to get posted to is either /api/v0.1/builds or /api/v0.2/builds. The post is currently being done using this factory:

```
app.factory("BuildWrite", function($resource) {
    return $resource("/api/v:apiVer/builds/:id", {apiVer: "@apiVer"}, {
        patch: {method: "PATCH"},
        save:  {method: "POST"}
    });
});
```

...and I call the factory from the controller with this:

```
if (build.osedition == “blah”) {
    var apiVer = "0.1";
} else {
    var apiVer = “0.2”;
}
BuildWrite.save({apiVer: apiVer}, build).$promise.then( … )
```

This is working fine, but because this factory is called from several places/controllers, I think it would be far neater if I could move the logic that sets `apiVer` to the factory itself, by getting the factory to inspect the POST request payload before returning the `$resource` function. Something like this:

```
app.factory("BuildWrite", function($resource) {
    if (data.osedition == “blah”) {
        var apiVer = "0.1";
    } else {
        var apiVer = “0.2”;
    }
    return $resource("/api/v” + apiVer + “/builds/:id", {}, {
        patch: {method: "PATCH"},
        save:  {method: "POST"}
    });
});
```

Obviously `data` is undefined here, but I've tried a number of approaches and just cant work out how to access the request payload from within the factory...is it even possible? Am I going about this completely the wrong way?

Any help will be much appreciated please.

Comment: Make it provider instead of factory & configure API version from `.config` phase of Angular app..

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Pankaj, but I'm afraid I dont understand what you mean exactly. Could you elaborate please?...